# How can i make an empty matrix that ican fill it out later by floats and strings

Tags: python, numpy, import

I want to make a matrix that at the first of program, i can't understand how many rows it has and during the program i will add each row to the matrix by using "vstack".

**Each row of these matrix consist of 100 elements,some strings and some floats.**

```
Y=[]
```

and later during the program i will make a new row in y array and i want to add it to Y.

```
Y=numpy.vstack([Y,y])
```

The error:

```
return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)


ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

I know that  for using "vstack" I need to have "Y" with the same dimension s as y but here I don't know how can i define that.

I tried this way too:

```
Y=[]
```

And later by using h starting from 0 `Y[h]=y`

Error: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: `Y=[]` defines an empty array, not an array.  `np.array([]) is an array, but without any elements (shape `(0,)`).  Step back from `vstack`, and practice defining arrays of various sizes. And since you are mixing strings and floats read up on structured arrays.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335649/what-does-this-parameter-in-numpy-zeros-method-mean on how to create and fill a structured array.