# What does this parameter in numpy.zeros method mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this piece of code and I am finding it difficult to understand what is advantage of defining the `numpy.zeros` method the way it is as shown below.

```
Z = np.zeros((10,10), [('x',float),('y',float)])
Z['x'], Z['y'] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,10),
                         np.linspace(0,1,10))

print(Z)
```

What is the significance of mentioning of `x` and `y`?

Comment: `Z` is a *structured array* (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), with fields `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret of the output is at `numpy.linspace(0,1,10)`, outputs an numpy.array, with:

```
[ 0.          0.11111111  0.22222222  0.33333333  0.44444444  0.55555556
  0.66666667  0.77777778  0.88888889  1.        ]
```

For `'x'` shape, as for `'y'`, where `'0'` is where it starts, `'1'` is where is stops, with `10` samples.

The `numpy.zeros()` are defining a matrix shape *(M, N) for ‘ij’ indexing*, where `M = N = 10`

The `numpy.meshgrid()` indexes into the matrix the values of `linspace` results, like *ai, aj*

e.g.

```
Z = np.zeros((10,10), [('x',int),('y',int)])
Z['x'], Z['y'] = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(0,10,10), np.linspace(0,10,10))
print Z
```

Outputs:

```
[[(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 0) (6, 0) (7, 0) (8, 0) (10, 0)]
 [(0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1) (6, 1) (7, 1) (8, 1) (10, 1)]
 [(0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2) (4, 2) (5, 2) (6, 2) (7, 2) (8, 2) (10, 2)]
 [(0, 3) (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 3) (4, 3) (5, 3) (6, 3) (7, 3) (8, 3) (10, 3)]
 [(0, 4) (1, 4) (2, 4) (3, 4) (4, 4) (5, 4) (6, 4) (7, 4) (8, 4) (10, 4)]
 [(0, 5) (1, 5) (2, 5) (3, 5) (4, 5) (5, 5) (6, 5) (7, 5) (8, 5) (10, 5)]
 [(0, 6) (1, 6) (2, 6) (3, 6) (4, 6) (5, 6) (6, 6) (7, 6) (8, 6) (10, 6)]
 [(0, 7) (1, 7) (2, 7) (3, 7) (4, 7) (5, 7) (6, 7) (7, 7) (8, 7) (10, 7)]
 [(0, 8) (1, 8) (2, 8) (3, 8) (4, 8) (5, 8) (6, 8) (7, 8) (8, 8) (10, 8)]
 [(0, 10) (1, 10) (2, 10) (3, 10) (4, 10) (5, 10) (6, 10) (7, 10) (8, 10)
  (10, 10)]]
```

Outputting a matrix `ij` scalars.

Check the next url's:

1. [numpy.linspace()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)
2. [numpy.zeros()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)
3. [numpy.meshgrid()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

This is actually defining two separate ndarrays, one named `'x'` and the other `'y'`.  While, in this case, it is unnecessary to specify the `dtype`s, it is a way of creating this type of double `ndarray`.

While this usage is not explicitly included in the [`numpy.zeros` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), they do show an example using it.

---

Edit:

@WarrenWeckesser links some [documentation for these `structured arrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

The `zeros` creates a `(10,10)` array, where each element has `dtype` defined by  `np.dtype([('x',float),('y',float)])`.  That is, each element consists of 2 floats, one called 'x', the other 'y'.

```
Z = np.zeros((10,10), [('x',float),('y',float)])
```

In a sense this makes a `(10,10,2)` array, except that there is a 'wall' between the `2` dimension, and the others.  For example you can't swap it one other other dimensions.  But it is possible to 'view' it as a (10,10,2) array:

```
Z.view('float').reshape(10,10,2)
```

The 2 fields of `Z` are indexed with `Z['x']` and `Z['y']`, the resulting views are each `(10,10)` arrays.

The 2nd line sets the values of these 2 fields

```
Z['x'], Z['y'] = np.meshgrid ...
```

Normally `meshgrid` returns 2 arrays, `X, Y = np.meshgrid...`.  So this is just a normal Python assignment.

I haven't seen this pairing of a structured array and meshgrid before, but it makes sense.  Whether it is all that useful in another matter.

I was going to add an example of what `Z` looks like, but @AndreL has done that for us.  Note that the elements `Z` are displayed as `tuples`, implying they are different from 2 element columns of a 3d array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation